# Finding the volume of the solid by the method of areas (math subject GRE exam 1268 Q.22)

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, volume

The question is in the following picture:

> [image]

The solution of the question is in the following video,
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2zry1DM7I8U&list=PL81IATpFpPBgrG8fZ3tRO41nNypY5xtEP&index=22,  by integration, but the lecturer in the video mentioned the solution by areas, he guesses that the area is 9 but I did not understand why he guesses this. Could anyone explain for me this method please?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He approximates the solid with a (generalized) cylinder, having a base of area around $3$ and a height of $3$. I wrote "generalized" cylinder, because you are probably only familiar with cylinders whose base is a circle, but the actual shape of the base is not important: the volume of the cylinder can be always computed as base area $\times$ height.

This estimate is actually a lower bound, because the upper surface of the solid is not horizontal, and its distance from the cylinder base is $\ge3$. So the lecturer can guess that the volume of the cylinder must be somewhat greater than $9$: that is enough to choose the right answer among the given alternatives.

Comment: Why he approximated the base area by 3? this point is not clear for me.

Comment: why the upper surface of the solid is not horizontal ? is this because of the "y" in y+3? is the upper surface of the cylinder oblique?

Comment: The area estimate is clearly explained in the video: he argues that the space between those two parabolas takes more than half of a $2\times2$ square, hence its area should be something more than $2$, probably around $3$. And yes, the upper face of the cylinder is oblique: it would have been horizontal if its equation had been $z=3$.